# Tell to Symfony's Request that some ajax request (jquery's $.get(path, cb) request) is a request with "X-Requested-With" equals to "XMLHttpRequest"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have an'ajax request done with jquery, and a Symfony2 controller that responds to this request with a json (if understand that is an'ajax request) or with a response (if not).

Ajax request:

```
$.get('path/to/bla/bla/', function () {
    // do something ...
})
```

Symfony's Action

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class FooController {
    public function barAction(Request $request) {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // json response
        } else {
            // normal response
        }
    }
}
```

Can I fix the header "X-Requested-With" of jquery $.get to XMLHttpRequest?

```
HttpFoundation/Request::isXmlHttpRequest() {
    return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use $.ajaxSetup to change the default `header` option for `X-Requested-With`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
});
```

Note however that XMLHttpRequest is already the default setting.

If you're trying to do this for a **JSONP** request, that simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

in this situation the only thing that changes is the view of the controller, for a simple case I would do the following

```php
  //...

  /**
   * @Route("/index.{format}", defaults={"format" = "html"})
   */
  public function indexAction($format)
  {
      return $this->render("ByteinCoffeeWebBundle:Frontend/User:index.$format.twig");
  }

  //...
```

but if this is a common thing in your application i guess better take a look in this package: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle